# .cspkg size difference when using cspack versus VS2012

Tags: azure

When using a VS2012 "Package" command on a cloud project, I get a 9mb .cspkg file versus 7mb when calling the azure sdk cspack.exe directly. Something important must be left out when using the command line,  I'm using this for a continuous build server - i'm hoping there's a better way to package a cloud project on a build server than calling cspack.exe, in case there isn't however

command I call in powershell at the end of a MSBuild (Bamboo Task)

```
& cspack "$cloudProject/ServiceDefinition.csdef" "/role:$role;$rolePath"         "/rolePropertiesFile:$role;$propertiesFile" "/sites:$role;Web;$rolePath" "/out:CmsBase.Cloud.cspkg" "/generateConfigurationFile:ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg"
```

The error I see when I deploy the 7mb package to azure is a 404 when calling http://xyz.com/Message/Index where Message is a MVC controller. The simulator and deployment from within vs2012 works as expected.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried /copyOnly flag and verify what is missing? In my case it is diagnostics agent is what missing and I am trying to figure out the way to put it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your /role argument. Looking at the examples on the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx page they don't add the path, only the name of the DLL for the entry point.  Your use of /role:$role;$rolePath is putting a path in there.  If the value for $role is the same as the assembly name that contains the role entry point then instead put /role:$role;$role to see where that gets you.

You can also directly call the CSPack build task that ships with the Azure SDK tools with MSBuild.  This is the same task that VS calls when you use the package command.  There is an article on WindowsAzure.com that describes this: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/#step2.  If you have questions about what parameters are being passed to the CSPACK MSBuild Task you can turn your MSBuild verbosity to diagnostics under Tools -> Options > Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run.  Then run the Package command and look at what it's being fed.

If you are interested in trying to track down what exactly isn't getting included then you can dig into the cspkg files that were produced.  Rename them .zip from .cspkg and extract the contents.  Inside each one there will be a .cssx file for each role you are deploying.  Rename this .cssx file to .zip and also extract it.  Now you'll see the contents that will be delivered to your role instances when they start up.  Using a file compare tool like winDiff, Beyond Compare, etc. you should be able to see what files are different and missing between the two.  That might be able to help pinpoint the difference.